# Can't connect multiple user to L2TP VPN server (Error 720)

Tags: vpn, vps, l2tp

I have a VPS running windows server 2008 r2 standard.

I configured Routing And Remote Access and NAT , i created multiple users with "Network Access Permission: Allow Access" .

What i have done in routing and remote access:

- i set up 21 static IP Address in IPv4 , from 10.10.10.50 to 10.10.10.70
- i set up preshared key in security tab.
- i created a NAT interface, in "service and ports" tab i set VPN Gateway L2TP private address to 10.10.10.50

The Problem is: I can connect to VPN by only one user account simultaneously , when one account is connected , other account gives this error: "Error 720: A connection to the remote computer could not be established. you might need to change the network settings for this connection."

please help me!